# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Multi-Docker Deployment Failure

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to deploy a multi-docker environment on EB and running into a strange error. I can't figure out what's causing it.

This is the Dockerrun file:

```
    {
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "command": [
                "celery",
                "-A",
                "grmrptcore",
                "worker",
                "-l",
                "INFO",
                "-B"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PYTHONPATH",
                    "value": "/usr/local/bin:/bin/"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CELERY_BROKER",
                    "value": "redis://redis:6379/0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CELERY_BACKEND",
                    "value": "redis://redis:6379/0"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "alexphi981/grmrptcore",
            "memory": 1024,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/opt/python/log/",
                    "sourceVolume": "celery_log"
                }
            ],
            "name": "celery"
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "python3",
                "manage.py",
                "runserver",
                "0.0.0.0:8000"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PYTHONPATH",
                    "value": "/usr/local/bin:/bin/"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CELERY_BROKER",
                    "value": "redis://redis:6379/0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "CELERY_BACKEND",
                    "value": "redis://redis:6379/0"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "image": "alexphi981/grmrptcore",
            "memory": 1024,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/opt/python/log/",
                    "sourceVolume": "django_log"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/src/static",
                    "sourceVolume": "Static_Volume"
                }
            ],
            "name": "django",
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl",
                    "-f",
                    "http://0.0.0.0:8000/",
                    "||",
                    "exit",
                    "1"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "command": [
                "python3",
                "manage.py",
                "migrate"
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PYTHONPATH",
                    "value": "/usr/local/bin:/bin/"
                }
            ],
            "essential": false,
            "image": "alexphi981/grmrptcore",
            "memory": 200,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/opt/python/log/",
                    "sourceVolume": "migrate_log"
                }
            ],
            "name": "migrate"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "alexphi981/nginx",
            "memory": 200,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/src/static",
                    "sourceVolume": "Static_Volume"
                },
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/log/nginx/",
                    "sourceVolume": "VarLogNginx"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "django",
                    "condition": "HEALTHY"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "redis:alpine",
            "memory": 200,
            "name": "redis"
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/log/containers/django"
            },
            "name": "django_log"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "static_volume"
            },
            "name": "Static_Volume"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/log/containers/celery"
            },
            "name": "celery_log"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/log/containers/migrate"
            },
            "name": "migrate_log"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/var/log/nginx/"
            },
            "name": "VarLogNginx"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the snippet from the ECS logs when the containers shut down.

```
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: handling container change event [STOPPED]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: container change STOPPED->STOPPED is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:42:55Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: task not steady state or terminal; progressing it" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=celery runtimeID=fee78a33b6b1e20e1cb9eee77fa716089a868c4e4419df57bd39225f5262cd6b]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=celery runtimeID=fee78a33b6b1e20e1cb9eee77fa716089a868c4e4419df57bd39225f5262cd6b]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: handling container change event [STOPPED]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: container change STOPPED->STOPPED is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:00Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: task not steady state or terminal; progressing it" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=celery runtimeID=fee78a33b6b1e20e1cb9eee77fa716089a868c4e4419df57bd39225f5262cd6b]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=celery runtimeID=fee78a33b6b1e20e1cb9eee77fa716089a868c4e4419df57bd39225f5262cd6b]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=django runtimeID=ec5de30d3eb37fc225bd217551e2012a2a49fab8e8091a648ad978b38f9479a6]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: handling container change event [RUNNING]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=redis runtimeID=c6b7b687d8d20c1b01b968c90b3c109603e49c48f516a8ea24c588ca1833dfd4]: container change RUNNING->RUNNING is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: handling container change event [STOPPED]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=migrate runtimeID=d2429754e4064e42d11418fb1efa8c5817cfdbcc2a60c44b1c813424a1925029]: container change STOPPED->STOPPED is redundant" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:05Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:07Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: got acs event" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:07Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: new acs transition to: STOPPED; sequence number: 19; task stop sequence number: 0" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:07Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: task moving to stopped, adding to stopgroup with sequence number: 19" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:07Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: task not steady state or terminal; progressing it" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: stopping container [redis]" module=docker_task_engine.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: got resource [cgroup] event: [REMOVED]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Task engine [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: stopping container [celery]" module=docker_task_engine.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [celery]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (NONE->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [django]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (NONE->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [nginx]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (NONE->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [redis]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (NONE->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: task not steady state or terminal; progressing it" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: waiting for event for task" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [name=nginx runtimeID=]: handling container change event [STOPPED]" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: recording execution stopped time. Essential container [nginx] stopped at: 2021-01-02 20:43:10.87982964 +0000 UTC m=+75288.879649294" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [nginx]: sending container change event: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3 nginx -> STOPPED, Known Sent: NONE" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="Managed task [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3]: Container [nginx]: sent container change event: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3 nginx -> STOPPED, Known Sent: NONE" module=task_manager.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [celery]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (STOPPED->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [django]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (STOPPED->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
level=info time=2021-01-02T20:43:10Z msg="api/task: Updating task desired status to stopped because of container: [nginx]; task: [awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j:17 arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:133264740537:task/awseb-dockerdev-cnmyuv3v2j/8558587cb1944a4dacad07e44304b5a3, TaskStatus: (NONE->STOPPED) Containers: [celery (RUNNING->STOPPED),django (RUNNING->STOPPED),nginx (STOPPED->STOPPED),redis (RUNNING->STOPPED),migrate (STOPPED->STOPPED),]]" module=task.go
```

Note that the migrate container is expected to have stopped by now. It runs django migrations then exits, and the container is defined as non-essential so it doesn't pull down the whole deployment.

The error on the ECS task says it was stopped by user, but I didn't tell it to stop. The deployment obviously fails because the containers stop.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was one of my containers was "pending" since it depended on another container with an incorrect healthCheck command. The command always failed, causing an unhealthy state on that container, so the pending container never actually started.